# Pandas: using groupby with condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have df

```
i,Unnamed: 0,ID,active_seconds,subdomain,search_term,period,code,buy    
0,56574,08cd0141663315ce71e0121e3cd8d91f,6,market.yandex.ru,None,515,100.0,1.0  
1,56576,08cd0141663315ce71e0121e3cd8d91f,26,market.yandex.ru,None,515,100.0,1.0 
2,56578,08cd0141663315ce71e0121e3cd8d91f,14,market.yandex.ru,None,515,100.0,1.0 
3,56579,08cd0141663315ce71e0121e3cd8d91f,2,market.yandex.ru,None,515,100.0,1.0  
4,56581,08cd0141663315ce71e0121e3cd8d91f,8,market.yandex.ru,None,515,100.0,1.0  
5,56582,08cd0141663315ce71e0121e3cd8d91f,32,market.yandex.ru,None,515,100.0,1.0 
6,56583,08cd0141663315ce71e0121e3cd8d91f,16,market.yandex.ru,None,515,100.0,1.0 
7,56584,7602962fb83ac2e2a0cb44158ca88464,4,market.yandex.ru,None,515,100.0,2.0  
8,56585,7602962fb83ac2e2a0cb44158ca88464,10,market.yandex.ru,None,515,100.0,2.0 
9,56639,7602962fb83ac2e2a0cb44158ca88464,2,market.yandex.ru,None,516,100.0,2.0
```

I need to count sum of `active_seconds` to every ID,

```
df.groupby(['ID', 'buy']).agg({'active_seconds': sum}).rename(columns={'active_seconds': 'count_sec'}).reset_index()
```

But I need do it, if `buy == 2 or buy == 3`, if `buy == 1`, I need to print date from this df.

```
ID  date    buy
7602962fb83ac2e2a0cb44158ca88464    01.01.2016  1
bc8a731e4c7e6f6b96e56ebe7f766bcd    10.02.2016  1
a703114aa8a03495c3e042647212fa63    20.02.2016  2
```

How can I do that?

Comment: This "But I need do it, if buy == 2 or buy == 3, if buy == 1, I need to print date from this df." is confusing.  Try rewording it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to join with a different data frame when buy == 1. Assuming the first data frame is named df and the second data frame that contains dates is named df2 then this is my proposed solution:

```
df.groupby(['ID', 'buy']).agg({'active_seconds': sum}).rename(columns={'active_seconds': 'count_sec'}).reset_index().merge(df2, how='left', on=['ID','buy']).apply(lambda x: x['date'] if x['buy']==1 else x['count_sec'],axis=1)
```